# Tengo que guardar datos de personas generadas (por un api) introduciendo su cédula en una base de datos ( como en la imagen)

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero me presentan todos estos errores, como puede resolverlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estos son los datos que tengo que introduccir, y donde me da error en la linea 78
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero me presentan todos estos errores, como puede resolverlo?
Aqui pueden ver los codigos, que error pueden ver???

Comment: Perdon, quise decir en el titulo, "y estas tienen que guardarse automaticamente en la base de datos"

Comment: No tienes definidas las constantes `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASS`, `DB_NAME`. Tienes que definirlas con los datos de acceso a mysql.

Comment: @grilix Si estan definidas en una pestaña aparte llamada "configx.php" y la tengo asi: <?php        define('DB_HOST','localhost'); define('DB_USER','root'); define('DB_PASS','mysql'); define('DB_NAME','parcial1'(osea el nombre del proyecto) );

Comment: Recuerda poner código en vez de imagen, es más fácil analizar y poder sugerirte soluciones.

Comment: @Triby papacito, puse una imagen con mis codigo, que creo que viene siendo lo mismo que yo ponerlo manualmente

Comment: No es lo mismo, porque no podemos copiar código de una imagen para probarlo directamente, tendríamos que teclear todo. ¡Hay gran diferencia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, tienes un error en tu foreach, cámbialo por esto:

```
foreach($datos as $persona){
  ....
}
```

En segundo lugar, te recomiendo que la fecha no sea insertada como parámetro que del usuario si no de forma automática, así:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$zonaHoraria = date_default_timezone_get();
$horaFecha = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Puedes cambiar la región para ajustar la zona horario. Saludos.

Comment: la primera parte me sirvio, gracias!! la seg no la entendi en verdad, osea donde es que debo de poner eso que me pusiste???

Comment: Pides la cédula y fecha de confirmación al usuario, solo pide la cédula y la fecha de confirmación hazla con `$horaFecha`. Solo es reemplazar.